# Handling 23 hour day on daylight saving time

Tags: swift, datetime

I need to call an API with a start time and an end time to retrieve a 24 hour period of data.  I then show that in either UTC or DST depending on the date that the data is retrieved for.  For a given "date", in UTC, this should be 00:00 - 23:59:59.  Simple.  In UK DST, it should be "date"-1 day 23:00 to "date" 22:59:00.  I have startOfDay and endOfDay extensions that work perfectly other than for 2 days in the year.  On the day that we switch from UTC to DST, the day is only 23 hours long (and 25 hours on the switch back to UTC).  Using Date formatters and logic, how can I get my code to recognise the short and long days and return the correct 24 hour length (i.e. on the UTC<->DST days , start at 23:00:00UTC, end at 23:00:00UTC?

I have some playground code that shows the issue.

```
import UIKit

var greeting = "Hello, playground"
let selDateStr = ["2023-03-25T00:00:00Z",//UTC date
                  "2023-03-26T00:00:00Z",//DST change at 2am
                  "2023-03-27T00:00:00Z",//DST date
                  "2023-10-28T00:00:00Z",//DST date
                  "2023-10-29T00:00:00Z",//UTC change at 2am
                  "2023-10-30T00:00:00Z"//UTC date
]

var selDateDte = [Date]()

for dteStr in selDateStr {
    
    selDateDte.append(stringToDate(str: dteStr, format: "YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z"))
}

var i=0
for date in selDateDte {
    print("\(selDateStr[i]) \(date.startOfDay) \(date.endOfDay) \(date.isGMT)")
    i+=1
}

//print(dateToString(date: date, format: "HH:mm"))

func stringToDate(str: String, format: String) -> Date {
    //strip out decimals correponding to milliseconds
    let dateString = str.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\.\\d+", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = format
    return dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)!
}

extension Date {
    var dayAfter: Date { Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: noon)!}
    var dayBefore: Date { Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: noon)!}
    var hourBefore: Date {
        Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: -1, to: self)!
    }
    var noon: Date { Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 12, minute: 0, second: 0, of: self)! }
    var startOfDay: Date { Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: self) }
    var endOfDay: Date { Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .init(second: -1), to: dayAfter.startOfDay)! }
    var startOfMonth : Date {Calendar.current.date(from: Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month], from: self))!}
    var endOfMonth : Date {Calendar.current.date(byAdding: DateComponents(month: 1, day: -1), to: startOfMonth)!}
    var yearAfter: Date { Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .year, value: 1, to: noon)!}
    var weekAfter: Date { Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 7, to: noon)!}
    var isGMT: Bool {TimeZone.current.abbreviation(for: self) == "GMT"}
}
```

Which gives output of:

```
2023-03-25T00:00:00Z 2023-03-25 00:00:00 +0000 2023-03-25 23:59:59 +0000 true
2023-03-26T00:00:00Z 2023-03-26 00:00:00 +0000 2023-03-26 22:59:59 +0000 true
2023-03-27T00:00:00Z 2023-03-26 23:00:00 +0000 2023-03-27 22:59:59 +0000 false
2023-10-28T00:00:00Z 2023-10-27 23:00:00 +0000 2023-10-28 22:59:59 +0000 false
2023-10-29T00:00:00Z 2023-10-28 23:00:00 +0000 2023-10-29 23:59:59 +0000 false
2023-10-30T00:00:00Z 2023-10-30 00:00:00 +0000 2023-10-30 23:59:59 +0000 true
```

Comment: Start by fixing your date format: `"YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z"` should be `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"`. Two changes: `YYYY` to `yyyy` and `'Z` to `Z`.

Comment: First problem here is you are mixing timezones: the notion with `Z` is always UTC, and it has no DST. So when you say `"2023-03-27T00:00:00Z",//DST date` - it's incorrect. It's still a UTC time. Even if your local time happens to be the same, it's not really the same zone. I.e. it may be `UTC+00:00` zone or `UTC-00:00`, but it's a different timezone. So first of all consider that your input is always UTC, which may or may not match your local time.

Comment: Second problem: you are using `TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)` - don't do that if you want a correct local timezone (even if it happens to be GMT), because the docs tells you: "Time zones created with this never have daylight savings and the offset is constant no matter the date. ", but you actually want the proper DST handling. So instead define a timezone using `Timezone.current` (if your current always what you want), or `TimeZone(identifier: "Europe/London")` - or whatever the zone you want.

Comment: Third _possible_ issue: in `stringToDate` you seems forcing things into a specific timezone (from UTC), while all your utility functions use `Calendar.current` (that is any current zone). So I suggest instead standardize to 2 zones: UTC and local time, or UTC and some specific zone. Not more than that. So like I said above, if you use `Timezone.current` in `stringToDate` (which is a default BTW, and you don't need to set it), then you use UTC as a source, but then everything else is in local timezone

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @klangfarb.  You are correct, I had used multiple different ways of formatting dates and strings from dates and this lead to the confusion.  I have reworked the code as you suggested with two standard formats and this is now working logically.